# Como implementar Upload no FrameWorks PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf-2.2, upload, primefaces-3.5

Saudação para todos,
estava tentando implementar upload no meu projeto JSF2, porém no ato de clicar no botão salvar apareceu essa mensagem abaixo;

```
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2794)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2641)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1083)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.FileRenderer.decode(FileRenderer.java:91)
    ... 34 more
```

A mensagem de erro indica que o formulário exigi a presença do enctype="multipart/form-data"

Fiquei sem entender porque no formulário já tinha colocado o doctype na tag form como mostra abaixo;

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/LayoutSystem.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">



    <!-- xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" -->

    <ui:define name="titulo">Novas Notícias</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="corpo">

        <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h1>Novas Notícias</h1>

            <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

            <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:button value="Novo" />


                    <p:commandButton value="Salvar" id="botaoSalvar"
                        action="#{cadastroNoticiaBean.salvar}">
                        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@all"/>
                    </p:commandButton>

                </p:toolbarGroup>


                <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                    <p:button value="Pesquisa"
                        outcome="/noticias/PesquisaNoticias.xhtml" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>

            <div id="wrap">

                <div class="left-sidebar">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel1"
                        style="width: 50%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">


                        <p:outputLabel value="Titulo" for="titulo" />
                        <p:inputText id="titulo" size="20" maxlength="50"
                            value="#{cadastroNoticiaBean.noticia.titulo_noticia}" />

                        <p:outputLabel value="Data" for="data_noticia" />
                        <p:calendar id="data_noticia" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                            value="#{cadastroNoticiaBean.noticia.data_noticia}" />



                        <p:outputLabel value="Descrição" for="descricao" />

                        <p:inputText id="descricao" size="20" maxlength="250"
                            value="#{cadastroNoticiaBean.noticia.desc_noticia}" />



                        <p:outputLabel value="Foto" />
                        <h:inputFile value="#{cadastroNoticiaBean.arquivo}" />




                    </p:panelGrid>
                </div>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Tentei de várias maneiras resolver esse problema, então encontrei essa 
referencia de pesquisa;

http://blog.triadworks.com.br/upload-de-arquivos-com-jsf-2-2

Então resolvi trazer a seguinte solução abaixo;

TROQUEI  ESSA

```
<!-- p: é a referencia do PrimeFaces  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"     -->
                    <p:commandButton value="Salvar" id="botaoSalvar"
                        action="#{cadastroNoticiaBean.salvar}">
                        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@all"/>
                    </p:commandButton>
```

POR ESSA

```
<!-- p: é a referencia do jsf  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" -->
                    <h:commandButton value="Salvar" id="botaoSalvar"
                        action="#{cadastroNoticiaBean.salvar}">
                        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@all"/>
                    </h:commandButton>
```

p: é do PrimeFaces e o h: é do JSF, quando troquei o "p:"  pelo  "h:" pegou 
normalmente e tive sucesso em fazer o upload para a pasta.

O mais estranho é que funcionou mesmo a pagina XHTML apresenta erros como mostra na figura abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha duvida é o seguinte;
Tem como eu conseguir fazer upload usando o Frameworks do PrimeFaces?

Como faço para utilizar o Frameworks do PrimeFaces com upload e funcionar?

Por que será que funcionou somente com o FrameWorks do JSF2?

Usando dessa forma;

```
                <p:fileUpload
                    fileUploadListener="#{cadastroNoticiaBean.arquivo}"
                    mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" update="messages"
                    sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="3"
                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
```

dá esse erro;

```
jul 30, 2015 10:37:41 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/noticias/CadastroNoticias.xhtml]
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component for expression "messages" referenced from "form:j_idt41".
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.cannotFindComponent(SearchExpressionFacade.java:688)
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponentById(SearchExpressionFacade.java:506)
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveClientIds(SearchExpressionFacade.java:256)
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveClientIds(SearchExpressionFacade.java:154)
    at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer.encodeScript(FileUploadRenderer.java:84)
    at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer.encodeEnd(FileUploadRenderer.java:72)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeDynamicBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:131)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeTableBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:102)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeTableLayout(PanelGridRenderer.java:65)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:37)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1896)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesses docs do Primefaces que acho que eles vão resolver a sua pergunta: [Simple file upload](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/single.xhtml) e [Basic file upload](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml)

Comment: tentei isso, mas não deu certo.

Comment: Aparece algum erro usando esses links que te passei?

Comment: acabei de colocar na postagem.

Comment: O erro que mosta é que você não tem nenhuma tag com o id messages. E outra coisa que eu não sei se vai gerar mais erros é que ao inves de usar `cadastroNoticiaBean.arquivo` você deveria fazer um metodo que recebria a requisicao, assim como no exemplo.